# Google App Engine keeps deploying a new instance, or none at all (server error)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I built and deployed an app on GAE. Yesterday all seemed to be working fine, sending requests every few seconds to the app would be successful with a response time of about 2.5 seconds. Today GAE keeps deploying a new instance for every request, or fails to create even one, resulting in unacceptably high response times (and much higher charges) or even 500 server errors.

I tried to suspend and restart the app a few times, works again for a couple of requests, then reverts to the same behavior. On the console I can see that a new instance is immediately shut down after serving a request, or in case of server error, that GAE was unable to deploy a new instance.

I checked the quotas on the console, nothing seems to hint that I cannot send multiple requests from the same IP.

Has anyone experienced such issues, and if yes, what could be the cause(s) and remedies? Please note, I am very new to GAE so have no further clue right now on where to start.

EDIT: Just realized the average memory used by an instance (F2 in my case, which gives you 256MB) is very close to the max (250MB). Could it be the issue? I will upgrade to F4 (512MB) and see what happens.

Comment: Indeed, it sounds like your instances are running out of memory. Try increasing the max and seeing if the behavior remains.

Comment: always start investigations with the app logs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/logs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling) - a new instance may be created based on request rate, response latencies, and other application metrics.

Therefore, it’s expected behaviour for the GAE Standard instances to scale up and down depending on the traffic they receive.

Also, if the maximum memory usage for the instance class is reached, a shutdown process will be triggered as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#shutdown).

As for the failures to create a new instance, it’s hard to tell what may be causing it without the Stackdriver Logging information. At the top of my head, you may receive HTTP 500 errors due to having reached the [response limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/how-requests-are-handled#response_limits), but it could indeed happen for any other reason as well.

Finally, taking into account the nature of the issues, I think it’s a good idea testing the GAE app’s behaviour using a better instance class and comparing the results. If you no longer experience this using an F4 instance class, it’s safe to assume that the previous instance class was simply not enough to satisfy the app’s requirements.

Comment: Thanks Maxim, haven't seen any further error after upgrading to F4 instances, even under load testing (which showed the scaling worked like a charm). Was very lucky that the console showed me average memory consumed per instance, and noticed this accidentally. Unfortunately, the only error message in the log was "could not start instance". Hopefully, this question and your responses will help others facing a similar issue. Thanks!

Comment: @michaelp Thank you for the update. If my answer was helpful, please consider accepting it so it gets more visibility, since as you've said, it may help others.